# why the first click on a svg button doesn't work in angular?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a component in angular for cropping image using angular cropperjs,

```
<div class="cropper-container">
  <div class="angular-cropper">
    <angular-cropper
      #angularCropper
      [cropperOptions]="config"
      [imageUrl]="imageUrl"
      (export)="croppedImage()"
    >
    </angular-cropper>
  </div>
  <div class="check-button" (click)="onCropClick()">
    <svg class="check"
      width="48"
      height="48"
      viewBox="0 0 40 40"
      fill="none"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <path
        d="M26.9218 9.4481L16.6584 21.7548L13.0654 17.4482C12.7295 17.0452 12.3175 16.7123 11.8529 16.4685C11.3882 16.2247 10.8801 16.0747 10.3575 16.0272C9.83495 15.9797 9.30813 16.0356 8.80714 16.1917C8.30616 16.3477 7.84082 16.6009 7.4377 16.9367C7.03459 17.2726 6.70158 17.6845 6.45771 18.149C6.21383 18.6135 6.06386 19.1215 6.01635 19.6439C5.96884 20.1664 6.02473 20.6931 6.18082 21.1939C6.33691 21.6948 6.59015 22.16 6.92608 22.563L13.5887 30.5593C13.9632 31.0098 14.4322 31.3724 14.9626 31.6214C15.4929 31.8704 16.0716 31.9996 16.6575 32C17.2434 32.0004 17.8222 31.8719 18.3529 31.6235C18.8835 31.3752 19.353 31.0132 19.7281 30.5632L33.0612 14.5707C33.4001 14.168 33.6561 13.7024 33.8145 13.2005C33.973 12.6987 34.0307 12.1705 33.9845 11.6462C33.9383 11.122 33.7889 10.6121 33.5451 10.1457C33.3013 9.67928 32.9677 9.26561 32.5636 8.92841C32.1594 8.5912 31.6927 8.3371 31.1901 8.18067C30.6875 8.02424 30.1589 7.96858 29.6347 8.01686C29.1106 8.06515 28.6011 8.21643 28.1355 8.46204C27.67 8.70765 27.2575 9.04275 26.9218 9.4481Z"
        fill="#04D500"
      />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

when I use this component in another component, the first time that I click on button, it doesn't work and it's get triggered the second time